# Google sheets/forms send out email to respondent with template

Tags: forms, google-sheets

quite a complex sheets problem that I'm trying to solve, any help would be appreciated. It's split into two parts, one on formatting the appropriate data into the tables, and the next onto emailing it to a set group of people.

Firstly, I'd like to link the sheet to a google form. The premise of this is a item loan out system, so I'd like the user to enter 1) their name 2) up to 10 items they would like to loan out (where they would type in Item1, Item2, Item3...).
Each item has a tagged full name (FNItem1, FNItem2...) and serial number (SNItem1, SNItem2...).
I want all this data to be automatically formatted into two tables like the ones shown in the "Desired Output" Sheet. The data that is required is as follows.

1. Users Name (From Raw Data Sheet)
2. Item Full name (From Inventory List)
3. Item SN (From Inventory List)
4. Date out, just the date that the google form was submitted (From Raw Data Sheet)
5. Date in, just the date out + 1 month (From Raw Data Sheet)

Next, I want these tables to be automatically sent to 2 preset emails, and the respondents personal email.

Is there a way to automate this such that no human input is required?

Thank you for the help in advance, I really appreciate it.

I’ve included a link of a template that ive referenced throughout the post.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tRHTKQ-Y8_NwT0iHbB3MsjE3FqTLc3Zff_PjsUjcUcQ/edit

Have tried searching but can only find a way to respond using plugins

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your current script and the current issue of your script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: `Is there a way to automate this such that no human input is required?` Yes. Please read [Updating Google Doc Via Multiple Form Submissions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75769165/1330560) - this does most if not all of what you want to do.